# Odd $.each behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

Consider the following examples:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
$.each(x, function(){
    console.log(this);
});

var o1 = {x:1, y:2};
var o2 = {a:1, b:2};
var o3 = {d:1, e:2}
var y = [o1, o2, o3];
$.each(y, function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Both of these work as expected: `this` refers to the currently referenced object from the collection passed in.

However, the next example is truly odd.

```
var z = [null];
$.each(z, function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

In this example, you'll notice that the `window` is logged to the console.

Why is this the case?

It is easily remedied by doing more explicit parameterization like so:

```
$.each(z, function(key, value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

But I'm particularly curious as to why `this` refers to `window` in the previous example.

Comment: `More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.` So, if there is no element (null), you get the main parent.

Comment: @Cheery: With this construct, there is no DOM element involved.  `jQuery.each` is a function on arrays/objects, not a method on a jQuery DOM collection wrapper.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I know, it does not matter. Every global variable is window.var_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a peek at the source for `$.each`, and you will see what's going on here.

```
for (; i < length; i++) {
    value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);

    if (value === false) {
        break;
    }
}
```

<sub>From: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.each</sub>

jQuery is using `.call()` to trigger your callback function.  According to Mozilla's docs for `.call`:

> Note that *this* may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in [non-strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) code, **null** and **undefined** will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

<sub>From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call</sub>

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: [jQuery.each() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each()
>   function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an
>   object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an
>   array index and a corresponding array value each time.

More importantly:

> (The value can
>   also be accessed through the **this** keyword, **but Javascript will always
>   wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or
>   number value.)** The method returns its first argument, the object that
>   was iterated.

It looks to me like, since it is trying to wrap `null` as an object, jQuery must return `window` for you.

I would always suggest using the `value` (2nd parameter) of the callback function instead of `this` within these kinds of loops though.

```
$.each(z, function(key, value){
    console.log(value);
});
```